# Use REST API to create a case using form from website

Tags: case

Building an app for a class I am in and want to use the sales force API. I am having a hard time finding exactly what endpoints to use and the docs for creating a simple new case inside of sales force that goes to a support teams queue using a form I build in react.

It would use the form data to essentially be able to submit a case from the website.

Any help or links to proper docs would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You want Web to Case: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.setting_up_web-to-case.htm&type=5

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. There is an OOTB feature called web-to-case which you can find in setup

Comment: @identigral  I did not know that thank you. However if I wanted to build that feature myself and not use the OOTB feature just for practicing purposes and for class is there documentation on doing somthing like that? I have seen in some posts new sforce.SObject("Case") but not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: @cropredy Thank you!

Comment: REST API - Look at the example for creating a record

Comment: Have you tried Web2Case, You can easily create a FormPost.